# javascript lambda regex replace like this code C#?

Tags: javascript

Its possible javascript lambda replace like this

```
     m => m.Groups[1].Value +  "#"  + Regex.Split(new Regex(@"m").Replace(m.Groups[7].Value,"", 1), @"m").Sum(v => int.Parse(v)) + "y#"
```

please help me

Comment: Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: What is your input and expected output? It is possible to replace with a callback or capture groups in several useful ways in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
function(m) {
    return m[2] + "#"
        + m[8].replace('m', '')
            .split('m')
            .reduce(function(a, b) { return a + parseInt(b) }, 0)
        + "y#"
}
```

If not, maybe you can include in your question how you're calling this and some sample data...